# Vueify with vue-resource

Tags: laravel, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-resource

I cannot seem to get vue-resource to work with vueify. I have defined one vue component which i am including in my main.js file.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './my-component.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        myComponent: MyComponent
    }
});
```

My vue component file looks like this:

```js
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    // import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
    // Vue.use(VueResource);

    export default {
        template: '#my-component-template',

        created: () => {
            Vue.$http.get('/my/api/123',
                data => {
                    console.log(data)
                }, err => {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.error(err);
                }
            );
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the current state, I receive this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

If I comment out the two lines concerning vue-resource in my component file, the error I receive turns like this:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $url
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.3",
    "vue": "^1.0.25",
    "vue-resource": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile:

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

All existing answers on SO have not brought any results. Please help.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you uncomment Vue.use(VueResource); ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I receive: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: The redefine error usually happens because you have included vue-resource twice somewhere in your app. Are you by any chance importing your vue-resource file with elixir as well as with npm? Maybe put this on github if you are really struggling so we can take a look.

Comment: Will do that, asap.

Comment: Turns out I still had a leftover `script` tag in my layout file that included vue-resource. Now combined with the answer from Pantelis Peslis i got it working.

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the `$http` with `http`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)

export default {
  created: () => {
    Vue.http.get(...)
  }
}
```

Also, it's a good practice to install the `VueResource` into the `main` file and then, we could use the `this` keyword as @Jeff said.

To achieve that, you should change the `arrow function`, because `this` refers to the global object:

```js
// refers to the global object
created: () => {}

// refers to the Vue component
created () {
  this.$http.get(...)
}
```

Comment: Nice hint on the global object and the `this` bind, thanks

Comment: Changing `$http` to `http` did not solve the issue. But changing the arrow functions did the trick. I also had a leftover script tag in my layout file that included vue-resource.

Comment: To work the `Vue.http` you should import the Vue as described to the question and set the VueResource properly.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried adding `var VueResource = require('vue-resource');` in your root vue instance? also add `Vue.use(VueResource)`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you add the plugin in `main.js` using `Vue.use(VueResource)`, it adds the `$http` attribute to all Vue instances.  You don't need to re-do it in your component file.  Then you just use `this.$http`:

```
    created: () => {
        this.$http.get('/my/api/123',
            //...
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this also returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $url`